# Change audio volume(level) generate strange audiable "ring" noise

Tags: qt, audio, signal-processing, volume

I want to change PCM(1k sine wave) volume by multiply a fraction between 0~1, such as:

```
char singlebuffer[1764];
qreal   ProcessedVolume=0.5;

for (j=0;j<1764;j++)
    singlebuffer[j]=singlebuffer[j]*(ProcessedVolume);
```

The result audio is very strange when `ProceededVolume` not "1". The strange audio sounds like 1K sine mix with other "ring noise" or mix with other "metal kicking noise". However, when I use oscilloscope to monitor the output audio, it still perfect 1K, only minimize volume level. I also check FFT spectrum, still only has 1K signal. However it sounds very different from original 1K audio. 
Why ? Something wrong with my ear or I cannot simply multiply a fraction to original raw PCM data ?

Appreciate for any suggestions~

Comment: What kind of data is in "singlebuffer"? Is it actually 8-bit samples? If it's anything other than 8-bit samples, manipulating it as if it were is going to be problematic. 8-bit audio is pretty rare these days. Even if you are using 8-bit samples, multiplying a char by a double can produce odd results, because there is some ambiguity about whether the char should be treated as signed or unsigned. Perhaps you need to expand the char to a double explicitly, taking account of the sign, and then convert it back explicitly after the multiplication?

Comment: Good suggestion, my raw data should be 16bits signed PCM data, I should simply try 8bit PCM sample first. I will reply the result asap.

Comment: I test the 8bits sine wave, the result is much better. Thank you Kevin.